# Comparing two instances of class having big number of attributes

Tags: java, hash, equals

I have a class having more than 30 attributes.

I want to override the equals method in order to compare two instance of my class.

However I want to avoid re-write all the 30 attributes in my method as this

```
@Override
public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Address address = (Address) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.attr1, address.attr1) &&
            Objects.equals(this.attr2, address.attr2) &&
            Objects.equals(this.attr3, address.attr3) &&
            ......
            Objects.equals(this.attr30, address.attr30);

}
```

Have you a more simple and proper way ?

Comment: how about using reflection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is basically the type of boilerplate code that is necessary. Luckily, there are lots of developers just as annoyed of writing such code as you are. For reasons like that, Project Lombok was founded.

Please [see this link.](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)

As an example, see the following two code snippets extracted from the page that I linked above:

**Lombok**

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id", "shape"})
public class EqualsAndHashCodeExample {
  private transient int transientVar = 10;
  private String name;
  private double score;
  private Shape shape = new Square(5, 10);
  private String[] tags;
  private int id;

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
  public static class Square extends Shape {
    private final int width, height;

    public Square(int width, int height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
    }
  }
}
```

**Vanilla Java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EqualsAndHashCodeExample {
  private transient int transientVar = 10;
  private String name;
  private double score;
  private Shape shape = new Square(5, 10);
  private String[] tags;
  private int id;

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof EqualsAndHashCodeExample)) return false;
    EqualsAndHashCodeExample other = (EqualsAndHashCodeExample) o;
    if (!other.canEqual((Object)this)) return false;
    if (this.getName() == null ? other.getName() != null : !this.getName().equals(other.getName())) return false;
    if (Double.compare(this.score, other.score) != 0) return false;
    if (!Arrays.deepEquals(this.tags, other.tags)) return false;
    return true;
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    final int PRIME = 59;
    int result = 1;
    final long temp1 = Double.doubleToLongBits(this.score);
    result = (result*PRIME) + (this.name == null ? 43 : this.name.hashCode());
    result = (result*PRIME) + (int)(temp1 ^ (temp1 >>> 32));
    result = (result*PRIME) + Arrays.deepHashCode(this.tags);
    return result;
  }

  protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
    return other instanceof EqualsAndHashCodeExample;
  }

  public static class Square extends Shape {
    private final int width, height;

    public Square(int width, int height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o == this) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof Square)) return false;
      Square other = (Square) o;
      if (!other.canEqual((Object)this)) return false;
      if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
      if (this.width != other.width) return false;
      if (this.height != other.height) return false;
      return true;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
      final int PRIME = 59;
      int result = 1;
      result = (result*PRIME) + super.hashCode();
      result = (result*PRIME) + this.width;
      result = (result*PRIME) + this.height;
      return result;
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
      return other instanceof Square;
    }
  }
}
```

If you like this approach, I'd recommend checking out Project Lombok in its entirety. It really helps cleaning up your code!

**!!! Beware !!!**
In order to be able to actually use methods generated by Lombok, you need to install the Lombok plugin into your IDE! Otherwise, your IDE won't know of the automatically generated methods.

Comment: I like the solution because I already use Lombok in my project

Comment: In that case, using the `@EqualsAndHashcode` method is definitely the way to go!

If you already use Lombok's feature, you should definitely check out the `@Data` annotation. It is a convenience annotation that includes `@Getter`, `@Setter`, `@EqualsAndHashcode`, `@ToString` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

See this link:
[Lombok Data Annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)

Answer (score 2):

You have this method in apache commons library that uses reflection for compare them

```
org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(Object, Object)
```

Example

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;

public class MyObject {

   ...
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Reflection isnt making the system slower ?

Comment: Well, that's true... but depending where and how often you have to compare those objects you may use it.

Comment: Your solution is pretty good. ANd Im now aware about two pretty functions offered : EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals and HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode for the HashCode. I ll make a performance test to be sure that all is OK

Comment: I would really recommend not using reflection unless it's absolutely necessary. The performance impact might be little in small use cases. But this can quickly add up when calling the reflection methods often and/or implementing the approach in a lot of places. Reflection offers great power to a developer. But with great power, comes great responsibility. You should first reflect on alternative ways before falling back to reflection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lombok project to auto-generate hashCode and equals methods at build time .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Field` class in the `java.lang.reflect` package like so:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    //instanceof check, null check, etc

    Field[] fields = Address.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if (!field.get(this).equals(field.get((Address) o))) {
                return false;
            } //end if
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            //handle exception
        } //end try catch
    } //end for

    return true;
} //equals
```

Comment: reflection isnt slower ?

Comment: @taboubim I would run some performance tests, but reflection is one of the easiest ways to do what you want, whether you write it yourself or use a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unitils http://www.unitils.org/cookbook.html

```
import static org.unitils.reflectionassert.ReflectionAssert.*;
// Exact field-by-field comparison
assertReflectionEquals(new Person("John", "Doe", new Address("New street", 5, "Brussels")), 
                             new Person("John", "Doe", new Address("New street", 5, "Brussels"));
```